# sent data from id='myid' to myFunction();

Tags: javascript, html

the problem now that I sent the name of provinces to setCamera(); function but nothing happen.

```
<div class='fn'>
  <input id="ads" type="textbox" placeholder="Looking @">
  <a class="btnsearch" id="submit3"><i class="ion-ios-search"></i></a>
</div>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById('submit3').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setCamera();
});

function setCamera() {

  var address = document.getElementById('ads').value;

  geocoder.geocode({
    'ads': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(8);

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' +
        status);
    }
  });
}
```

but when I try this it works.

```
<input id="address" type="textbox1" placeholder="ex.กทม" value="" 
   class="box1" >
```

Javascript

```
    function codeAddress() {

        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(12);
            marker = new RichMarker({
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
              map: map,
              draggable: true,
              content: '<div class="my-marker">' +
              '<div class="dot"></div>' +
              '<div class="pulse"></div>' +
                '</div>'
              });

          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + 
           status);
          }
        });
      }
```

Any reason why my setCamara(): not working ? but my code Address seems to work very well.

Comment: It is working fine for me. Please check with "geocoder" you this is not defined at all so this is showing error. Are you declared "geocoder" anywhere else?

Comment: Why is that an `<a>` and not a `<button type="button">` in the first place?

Comment: Use the debugging tools in your browser. Open the Console. Look to see if any error messages are reported. Add logging statements to your functions. Check to see if the event listener gets called at all.

Comment: I think the code is executing before the actual HTML loaded. Move the script before the `</body>` tag and check it out. when i move the code inside the `<head>` section, i am getting the console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`. are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: `address` is the keyword for getting geocode. don't change it. you can keep any `id` name for your `input` tag.

Comment: you mean this line ?  [geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address},] @SureshPonnukalai

Comment: yes..left side is the key value. don't change it. right side one is your variable, that you can named as anything.

Comment: a haaa now it works thank you @SureshPonnukalai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `href` in `<a>`.

Event is triggering on click of `<a>`.

Check it out the below one.

```js
document.getElementById('submit3').addEventListener('click', function() {
alert("On click event is triggered..");
setCamera();
});

         function setCamera() {
alert("on func camera");
          var address = document.getElementById('ads').value;

          geocoder.geocode( { 'ads': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
              map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
              map.setZoom(8);

            } else {
              alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' 
            + status);
            }
          });
        }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='fn'>
   <input id="ads" type="textbox"  placeholder="Looking @" >
  <a href ="" class="btnsearch"  id="submit3"  ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>
   </div>
```

Comment: is that `href` really required for the click event work??

Comment: Glad to know@ChanwitKongthong. Click the tick symbol as well. If you find it useful.